# Java 7 generics type inference fails

Tags: java, generics, type-inference, rx-java

I have the following method:

```
protected <T> Func1<ApiResponse<T>, Observable<T>> checkApiSuccess() {
    return new Func1<ApiResponse<T>, Observable<T>>() {
        @Override
        public Observable<T> call(ApiResponse<T> response) {
            if (response.isSuccess()) {
                return Observable.from(response.getResult());
            }

            return Observable.error(new ApiException(response.getError()));
        }
    };
}
```

Why does this work:

```
Func1<ApiResponse<LoginResult>, Observable<LoginResult>>
        checkApiSuccessFunc = checkApiSuccess();

return apiService
        .login(params)
        .flatMap(checkApiSuccessFunc);
```

but this doesn't:

```
return apiService
        .login(params)
        .flatMap(checkApiSuccess());
```

I get the compile-time error `no suitable method found for flatMap(Func1<ApiResponse<Object>>, Observable<Object>)`. Somehow when using the method directly the type T can't be mapped to LoginResult anymore.

Comment: Signature of flatMap?

Comment: By the way, streams are a part of Java 8. How is this Java 7?

Comment: @Andrew: ```public final <R> Observable<R> flatMap(Func1<? super T,? extends Observable<? extends R>> func)```

Comment: @RealSkeptic: I'm using RxJava which also has a flatMap method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type inference probably can't determine that the `T` should be a `LoginResult`. It may work with Java 8 where the type inference system has been improved.

You could try using a target type to help the compiler:

```
flatMap(this.<LoginResult> checkApiSuccess())
```

Comment: I didn't know you could specify the type using ```this.<Foo>```. Learned something new today, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In

```
Func1<ApiResponse<LoginResult>, Observable<LoginResult>>
        checkApiSuccessFunc = checkApiSuccess();

return apiService
        .login(params)
        .flatMap(checkApiSuccessFunc);
```

The compiler infers from the declared type of checkApiSuccessFunc what the return type of `checkAPISuccess()` is, and from this infers everything inside it.

But in

```
return apiService
        .login(params)
        .flatMap(checkApiSuccess());
```

There is really not enough information to infer the type of `checkApiSuccess()`. `flatMap` expects the function to take an `<? super T>` parameter. So it expects something which is a superclass of whatever `login` emits, and since you have nothing that limits it, it infers `Object`. You haven't mentioned what the signature function that this `return` is called for 
is.